# Emtpy "ca.crt" file from cert-manager

Tags: ssl, kubernetes, tls1.2, cert-manager

I use `cert-manager` to generate TLS certificates for my application on Kubernetes with Let's Encrypt.

It is running and I can see "ca.crt", "tls.crt" and "tsl.key" inside the container of my application (in `/etc/letsencrypt/`).

But "ca.crt" is empty, and the application complains about it (`Error: Unable to load CA certificates. Check cafile "/etc/letsencrypt/ca.crt"`). The two other files look like normal certificates.

What does that mean?

Comment: What document do you follow?

Comment: @yasinlachini this: https://docs.cert-manager.io/en/latest/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed this:

```
$ kubectl describe certificate iot-mysmartliving -n mqtt
...
Status:
  Conditions:
    ...
    Message:  Certificate issuance in progress. Temporary certificate issued.
```

and a related line in the docs:

https://docs.cert-manager.io/en/latest/tasks/issuing-certificates/index.html?highlight=gce#temporary-certificates-whilst-issuing

They explain that the two existing certificates are generated for some compatibility, but they are not valid until the issuer has done its work.

So that suggests that the issuer is not properly set up.

---

**Edit**: yes it was. The DNS challenge was failing, the debug line that helped was

```
kubectl describe challenge --all-namespaces=true
```

More generally,

```
kubectl describe clusterissuer,certificate,order,challenge --all-namespaces=true
```

Comment: yes may possible go inside the cluster-issuer or issuer however you have setup and check the events of the issuer.

Answer (score 2):

With cert-manager you have to use the `nginx-ingress` controller which will work as expose point.

ingress nginx controller will create one load balancer and you can setup your application tls certificate there.

There is nothing regarding certificate inside the pod of cert-manager.

so setup nginx ingress with cert-manager that will help to manage the tls certificate. that certificate will be stored in kubernetes secret.

Please follow this guide for more details:

> https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-an-nginx-ingress-with-cert-manager-on-digitalocean-kubernetes

Comment: Ingresses work only for HTTP traffic, if I understood well. Since I have something else (MQTT), does that mean that I cannot use cert-manager for it?

Comment: you can follow this guide also `https://dzone.com/articles/secure-communication-with-tls-and-the-mosquitto-broker`

Comment: or you can create the certificate locally upload it to kubernetes secret and use secret on ingress.

Comment: So you mean there is no other way than to generate my own CA certificate? I though I could reuse some external authority like letsencrypt does.

Comment: @JulienD i have not did that before for mqtt with https only i have worked so.

Comment: but if something like there ssl for mqtt then it's better to try it out like generating the manual certificate and add it in the secret of kubernetes.

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation, cafile is for something else (trusted root certificates), and it would probably be more correct to use capath /etc/ssl/certs on most systems.

You can follow this guide if you have Windows Operating System:
[tls](https://dzone.com/articles/secure-communication-with-tls-and-the-mosquitto-broker).
Article is about how to enable Mosquitto and clients to use the TLS protocol.

Establishing a secure TLS connection to the Mosquitto broker requires key and certificate files. Creating all these files with the correct settings is not the easiest thing, but is rewarded with a secure way to communicate with the MQTT broker.

If you want to use TLS certificates you've generated using the Let's Encrypt service.
You need to be aware that current versions of mosquitto never update listener settings when running, so when you regenerate the server certificates you will need to completely restart the broker.

If you use DigitalOcean Kubernetes try to follow this instruction: [ca-ninx](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-an-nginx-ingress-with-cert-manager-on-digitalocean-kubernetes), you can use Cert-Manager and ingress nginx controller, they will work like certbot.

Another solution is to  create the certificate locally on your machine and then upload it to kubernetes secret and use secret on ingress.

Comment: This is about creating my own CA ("1. Create a CA keypair"). What I want is the equivalent of `certbot` that was running fine without me worrying, but on Kubernetes.

Comment: @JulienD you can use certmanager and ingress nginx controller so it will work like certbot.